# how to set jquery variable as id

Tags: jquery, html

i want to set a jquery variable as id. Here is my jquery variable

```
var key = $(this).prev().attr('data');
```

i want to do it like

```
$("#".key).html(result.vote);
```

thanks

Comment: Do: `$("#"+key).html(result.vote)`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this:

```
$("#"+key).html(result.vote);
```

What you are trying to do is correct. But in jQuery/java script concatenate operator is '**+**' not '**.**'.

Answer (score 4):

You have missed `+` for combining id selector with some variable.It should be:

```
$("#"+key).html(result.vote);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#"+key)` you must contatenate